# ruby string array iteration. Array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, loops

I have a ruby problem

Here's what i'm trying to do

```
def iterate1               #define method in given class
 @var3 = @var2.split(" ")  #split string to array
 @var4 = @var3

 @var4.each do |i|         #for each array item do i
   ra = []
   i.each_char {|d|  ra << counter1(d)}  # for each char in i, apply def counter1

   @sum = ra.inject(:+)                  

   @sum2 = @sum.inject(:+)               #have to do the inject twice to get values

 end

@sum2
```

I know i have over complicated this

Basically the input is a string of letters and values like "14556 this word 398"

I am trying to sum the numbers in each value, seperated by the whitespace like (" ")

When i use the def iterate1 method the block calls the counter1 method just fine, but i can only get the value for the last word or value in the string.

In this case that's 398, which when summed would be 27.

If i include a break i get the first value, which would be 21.

I'm looking to output an array with all of the summed values

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd recommend converting all these ivars to local vars and renaming them properly first.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're after:

```
"10 d 20 c".scan(/\b\d+\b/).map(&:to_i).inject(:+) # Returns 30
```

`scan(/\b\d+\b/)` will extract all numbers that are made up of digits only in an array, `map(&:to_i)` will convert them to integers and I guess you already know what `inject(:+)` will do.

I'm not sure if I understand what you're after correctly, though, so it might help if you provide the answer you expect to this input.

EDIT:

If you want to sum the digits in each number, you can do it with:

```
"12 d 34 c".scan(/\b\d+\b/).map { |x| x.chars.map(&:to_i).inject(:+) }
```

`x.chars` will return an enumerator for the digits, `map(&:to_i)` will convert them to integers and `inject(:+)` will sum them.

Comment: im actually looking for each value to be a separate array item, like [27, 21] etc

Comment: where would i put the call to my counter1 method. i need to run that method on each value

Comment: I don't think I understand your issue :) . If you need to call this on every string containing digits, you can just put a piece of the code I posted in a method and pass the string as an argument. Can you please elaborate? :)

Comment: Right Okay. I'm going to go another direction with it after getting advice from a friend. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to use `map` instead of `each` because the former collects the results and returns an array. e.g:

```
def iterate1               #define method in given class
 @var3 = @var2.split(" ")  #split string to array
 @var4 = @var3

 @var4.map do |i|         #for each array item do i
   ra = []
   i.each_char {|d|  ra << counter1(d)}  # for each char in i, apply def counter1

   @sum = ra.inject(:+)                  
   @sum2 = @sum.inject(:+)               #have to do the inject twice to get values
 end
end
```

You could write it a lot cleaner though and I think Stefan was a big help. You could solve the issue with a little modification of his code

```
# when you call iterate, you should pass in the value
# even if you have an instance variable available (e.g. @var2)
def iterate(thing)
  thing.scan(/\b\d+\b/).map do |x| 
    x.chars.map{|d| counter1(d)}.inject(:+)
  end
end
```

The above assumes that the `counter1` method returns back the value as an integer